# How to change font in lhs2tex output

Tags: fonts, lhs2tex

Documentation for lhs2tex shows a serif font being used by default as the output from the preprocessor (http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/Guide2-1.17.pdf):

[image: desired-font]

However, when I run `lhs2tex --poly input.lhs > out.tex;pdflatex out.tex`, the Haskell source is formatted in a computer-modern font:

[image: output-font]

My input file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\%include polycode.fmt
\begin{document}
Hello World!

> main :: IO ()
> main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"

\end{document}
```

Comment: Computer Modern is a serif font? Well, Computer Modern Roman is a serif font, Computer Modern Sans serif is, ähm, sans-serif font.

Comment: sorry -  I am probably not referring to the font correctly. I've added screenshots to help describe the current issue

Comment: To be honest, i don't know how that works in detail and i won't read the doc. Try to add `\usepackage{tgchorus}` to your inputfile and see if there are differences.

Comment: thanks. that still gives the same result though. I think the issue is related to the polytable package not being found, although no errors are shown when running pdflatex

Comment: You can make some edit to the question, add some detail, this will make the question appear back on top of the main site. Do it at around 20 pm standard time, most people online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that alignment in `lhs2TeX` (which uses the `polytable` packake) is driven by spaces in the `.lhs` source file. I was able to set the font using

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

and adjusting the input to

```
> main  ::   IO()
> main  =    putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

resolved the alignment issue.